# Is the past tense of "go" related to the word "venture"?

Tags: etymology, past-tense

I'm wondering whether the word "went" is a cognate of or otherwise related to "venture". Is it, despite the different spelling?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[*Etymonline* to the rescue!](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=venture) venture dates back to the 15th century, is a shortened form of Old French *aventure*, from Latin *adventura* (“about to happen”).

*Went*, on the other hand, was initially the past participle of [*wend*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=wend) (“to proceed on”), from Old English *wendan* (“to turn, go”), from Proto-Germanic *wandijanan*.

So: **no**, they are not related.

Comment: @ThirdIdiot: which proves that I'm precognitive!

Comment: Not sure at alll about that...

Answer (score 5):

- *Venture* ultimately comes from Latin *venire* (taking a rather interesting detour via *adventure* and *aventure*), from Proto-Indo-European base **gwa-* "to go, come", [whence the English *come*, the German *kommen*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=come) etc.
- *Went*, on the other hand, ultimately comes from Proto-Indo-European **wendh-* "to turn, wind, weave", whence the English *wend*, *wind* (verb, /waind/), the German *wenden*, *winden*, as well as the Latin *viere* "twist, plait, weave," and *vincire* "bind".

So *went* and *venture* are not related.